# Can You See What Webpage is Currently Open?

Tags: batch-file, html

I'm coding a program to ping a webpage and then give you the option to open it as a workaround for a WiFi filter (I want to access a blog which is blocked). So far I have been using this code:

```
set /p website=""
ping %website%
set /p websitestart=""
start iexplore.exe %websitestart%
exit
```

It works, but when you click on a link on the webpage, the filter comes into action and you have to run the program again with the extra information on the end of the URL, such as "www.google.co.uk**/images**". Sometimes the bit after the "/" can get very long and I was wondering, in Batch, is there a way to find out what particular webpage is open on Internet Explorer? For example, if I have Google open, is there a way in Batch for the program to find out I'm running Google?

If not, is there another programming language that allows this?

Comment: You should really never try to use "batch" for anything complex. Use PowerShell, which is not only a good command-line, it's also an actual programming language.

Comment: Or in fact, use a proxy or VPN to browse the web.  There are several options for doing this.